# JSON-RPC - Handling exceptions with TaskCompletionSource (SetException)

Tags: c#, .net-core, json-rpc, taskcompletionsource

There is a JSON-RPC API, which I'm currently implementing. It can be tested [here](https://www.deribit.com/api_console).

The problem is that if an incorrect DTO model is passed to `SendAsync<TResponse>`, `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` is going to throw a `JsonException`, which is not handled by my code. I know I've got to use `SetException` in some way, but I don't know how to do it, so here is the question. The exception message should be printed in the console as well.

```cs
public sealed class Client : IDisposable
{
    ...

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<long, IResponseHandler> _handlers = new();

    ...

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await foreach (var message in _client.Start(cancellationToken))
            {
                using var response = JsonDocument.Parse(message);

                try
                {
                    var requestId = response.RootElement.GetProperty("id").GetInt32();

                    // TODO: Handle JsonException errors via `SetException`?
                    // TODO: Show error when incorrect input parameters are filled
                    if (_handlers.ContainsKey(requestId))
                    {
                        _handlers[requestId].SetResult(message);
                        _handlers.TryRemove(requestId, out _);
                    }
                }
                catch (KeyNotFoundException)
                {
                    // My point is that a message should be processed only if it doesn't include `id`,
                    // because that means that the message is an actual web socket subscription.
                    _messageReceivedSubject.OnNext(message);
                }
            }
        }, cancellationToken);

        ...

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TResponse>(string method, object @params)
    {
        var request = new JsonRpcRequest<object>
        {
            JsonRpc = "2.0",
            Id = NextId(),
            Method = method,
            Params = @params
        };

        //var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResponse>();
        //_requestManager.Add(request.Id, request, tcs);

        var handler = new ResponseHandlerBase<TResponse>();
        _handlers[request.Id] = handler;

        var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

        _ = _client.SendAsync(message);

        return handler.Task;

        //return tcs.Task;
    }

    public async Task<AuthResponse?> AuthenticateAsync(string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var @params = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"grant_type", "client_credentials"},
            {"client_id", clientId},
            {"client_secret", clientSecret}
        };

        var response = await SendAsync<SocketResponse<AuthResponse>>("public/auth", @params).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return response.Result;
    }

    ...

    private interface IResponseHandler
    {
        void SetResult(string payload);
    }

    private class ResponseHandlerBase<TRes> : IResponseHandler
    {
        private readonly TaskCompletionSource<TRes> _tcs = new();

        public Task<TRes> Task => _tcs.Task;

        public void SetResult(string payload)
        {
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(payload, typeof(TRes));
            _tcs.SetResult((TRes) result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a JsonConverter in Nwetonsoft.Json? That should perfectly solve the issue.

Comment: @Zee, unfortunately I don't. It's no longer recommended. `System.Text.Json` should be.

Comment: What is `_client`? If you use the HTTP API, you don't have to keep track of requests yourself at all.

Comment: @StephenCleary, it is a `ClientWebSocket` wrapper, I'm using the web socket protocol instead of the HTTP.

Comment: @StephenCleary, people did it [here](https://github.com/tekr/DeribitDotNet/blob/b5770ff79b4cafa7df99f200846c4fb4bf87c47b/DeribitDotNet/DeribitApi.cs#L136-L159). Take a look at `HandleResponse` method too. But it's a bit hard to understand for me. A simplified version of it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally, I did something [very similar](https://youtu.be/oKP_OlVxO6Q?t=4752) while live-coding a [TCP/IP chat application](https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/TcpChat/commit/4d52ad18043f46964143be8813f442c281a98738) last week.

Since in this case you already have an `IAsyncEnumerable<string>` - and since you *can* get messages other than responses - I recommend also exposing that `IAsyncEnumerable<string>`:

```
public sealed class Client : IDisposable
{
  public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    await foreach (var message in _client.Start(cancellationToken))
    {
      // TODO: parse and handle responses for our requests
      yield return message;
    }
  }
}
```

You can change this to be Rx-based if you want (`_messageReceivedSubject.OnNext`), but I figure if you already have `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, then you may as well keep the same abstraction.

Then, you can parse and detect responses, passing along all other messages:

```
public sealed class Client : IDisposable
{
  public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    await foreach (var message in _client.Start(cancellationToken))
    {
      var (requestId, response) = TryParseResponse(message);
      if (requestId != null)
      {
        // TODO: handle
      }
      else
      {
        yield return message;
      }
    }

    (long? RequestId, JsonDocument? Response) TryParseResponse(string message)
    {
      try
      {
        var document = JsonDocument.Parse(message);
        var requestId = response.RootElement.GetProperty("id").GetInt32();
        return (document, requestId);
      }
      catch
      {
        return (null, null);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can define your collection of outstanding requests and handle messages that are for those requests:

```
public sealed class Client : IDisposable
{
  private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, TaskCompletionSource<JsonDocument>> _requests = new();

  public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    await foreach (var message in _client.Start(cancellationToken))
    {
      var (requestId, response) = TryParseResponse(message);
      if (requestId != null && _requests.TryRemove(requestId.Value, out var tcs))
      {
        tcs.TrySetResult(response);
      }
      else
      {
        yield return message;
      }
    }

    (long? RequestId, JsonDocument? Response) TryParseResponse(string message)
    {
      try
      {
        var document = JsonDocument.Parse(message);
        var requestId = response.RootElement.GetProperty("id").GetInt32();
        return (document, requestId);
      }
      catch
      {
        return (null, null);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the usage of `ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove`, which is safer than accessing the value and *then* removing it.

Now you can write your general `SendAsync`. As I note in my video, I prefer to split up the code that runs synchronously in `SendAsync` and the code that `await`s the response:

```
public sealed class Client : IDisposable
{
  ...

  public Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TResponse>(string method, object @params)
  {
    var request = new JsonRpcRequest<object>
    {
      JsonRpc = "2.0",
      Id = NextId(),
      Method = method,
      Params = @params,
    };

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<JsonDocument>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    _requests.TryAdd(request.Id, tcs);
    return SendRequestAndWaitForResponseAsync();

    async Task<TResponse> SendRequestAndWaitForResponseAsync()
    {
      var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
      await _client.SendAsync(message);
      var response = await tcs.Task;
      return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(response, typeof(TResponse));
    }
  }
}
```

I've removed the "handler" concept completely, since it was just providing the type for `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`. Also, by using a local `async` method, I can use the `async` state machine to propagate exceptions naturally.

Then, your higher-level methods can be built on this:

```
public sealed class Client : IDisposable
{
  ...

  public async Task<AuthResponse?> AuthenticateAsync(string clientId, string clientSecret)
  {
    var @params = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
      {"grant_type", "client_credentials"},
      {"client_id", clientId},
      {"client_secret", clientSecret}
    };

    var response = await SendAsync<SocketResponse<AuthResponse>>("public/auth", @params);
    return response.Result;
  }
}
```

So the final code ends up being:

```
public sealed class Client : IDisposable
{
  private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, TaskCompletionSource<JsonDocument>> _requests = new();

  public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    await foreach (var message in _client.Start(cancellationToken))
    {
      var (requestId, response) = TryParseResponse(message);
      if (requestId != null && _requests.TryRemove(requestId.Value, out var tcs))
      {
        tcs.TrySetResult(response);
      }
      else
      {
        yield return message;
      }
    }

    (long? RequestId, JsonDocument? Response) TryParseResponse(string message)
    {
      try
      {
        var document = JsonDocument.Parse(message);
        var requestId = response.RootElement.GetProperty("id").GetInt32();
        return (document, requestId);
      }
      catch
      {
        return (null, null);
      }
    }
  }

  public Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TResponse>(string method, object @params)
  {
    var request = new JsonRpcRequest<object>
    {
      JsonRpc = "2.0",
      Id = NextId(),
      Method = method,
      Params = @params,
    };

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<JsonDocument>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    _requests.TryAdd(request.Id, tcs);
    return SendRequestAndWaitForResponseAsync();

    async Task<TResponse> SendRequestAndWaitForResponseAsync()
    {
      var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
      await _client.SendAsync(message);
      var response = await tcs.Task;
      return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(response, typeof(TResponse));
    }
  }

  public async Task<AuthResponse?> AuthenticateAsync(string clientId, string clientSecret)
  {
    var @params = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
      {"grant_type", "client_credentials"},
      {"client_id", clientId},
      {"client_secret", clientSecret}
    };

    var response = await SendAsync<SocketResponse<AuthResponse>>("public/auth", @params);
    return response.Result;
  }
}
```

You may also want to check out [David Fowler's Project Bedrock](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework), which may simplify this code quite a bit.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much! There are two issues, because you probably haven't used an IntelliSense. https://pastebin.com/Up4RumYH. The first one is at `SendAsync<TResponse>`. `TaskCompletionSource<TResponse>` should be `TaskCompletionSource<JsonDocument>` in order for the error to go away, which breaks the generic structure. Is there a way to keep the generic method? The second one is at `_requests.TryRemove(requestId`, requestId is `long?`, which forces me to `requestId ?? -1`. I hope there is another way.

Comment: Yes, I just typed it into the answer. Both should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! There is a weird warning coming on from StartAsync and its CancellationToken param: `CS8425: Async-iterator '...StartAsync(CancellationToken)' has one or more parameters of type 'CancellationToken' but none of them is decorated with the 'EnumeratorCancellation' attribute, so the cancellation token parameter from the generated 'IAsyncEnumerable<>.GetAsyncEnumerator' will be consumed'.`

Comment: I believe it's about `.WithCancellation`, so here is what the actual ClientWebSocket implement has ` public IAsyncEnumerable<string> Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cancellationSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);`

Comment: Just add the `EnumeratorCancellation` attribute, then.